# Alternative of Session in Asp.net?

Tags: session, state-management

We are using Asp.net Session in our application for state management. By default, In-proc mode is being used. But now, we have to look for an alternative as we have been asked to remove Session from our application by our client due to performance issue.

One of the way is to keep everything at Client side say in hidden field on Postback. It's not a good approach for sure.

Is there any other way of doing it? Im sure there would be an alternative.

PS: Please don't suggest Querystring.

Thanks,

Sumit

Comment: *Please don't suggest Querystring.*  Why not!?

Comment: @dbaseman: The reason being the data would be so large. It will cross the maximum data limit that can be passed through Querystring.

Comment: I don't think there's enough info here to answer the question.  What do you mean by performance?  Server is out of memory?  Too much data being sent back and forth to the server?

Answer (score 1):

Something close to that is `HttpContext.Current.Items` but has a shorter life span

> Items collections of HttpContext is and IDictionary key-value
>   collections and that are shared across a single HTTPRequest. Yes,
>   HttpContext.Current.Items  valid for  a single HTTPRequest.  Once
>   after processing, server  information  is sent back to the browser,
>   the variables that were set in the Items[] collection will lost. Where
>   as for Session Variable, information valid for multiple request as
>   this is user specific. The session variable only  expires either on
>   Session Time Out or explicitly clear the values.

More from these articles

- [When we can use HttpContext.Current.Items to stores data in ASP.NET](http://abhijitjana.net/2011/01/14/when-we-can-use-httpcontext-current-items-to-stores-data-in-asp-net/)