# alternative to session variables, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, session

May sound like a dumb question but here goes.

I instantiate a LIST from my homepage, the list is in a global class file, and returns all the information about the person logging in. the person, could have one or more accounts associated with the site, and therefore i need to code against a default flag to display their default account informaiton. However, i then also need to build their other account information and display this for them.

The additional account(s) are listed in a drop down box. when the drop down box fires off, instead of calling out to the class again, and retrieving all the necessary information, as i've already done this once, how can i store the object, so that it can be used?

I've looked at Session Variables, but this gets a bit messy (I have 35 fields being returned in my list), plus, the Session variables only get set the first time around, not on DDL changed.

therefore, I need a way of having quick access to the object. - what's the best approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative of Session in Asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995622/alternative-of-session-in-asp-net)... Also look at [Session and ViewState alternative](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/214431/Session-and-ViewState-alternative)

Comment: I am, but would like to keep away from them if possible. The site is installed inside a Bureau and they are very strict about cookies.

Comment: Did you try the design with a webserver caching in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per me , Session is the best possible  object for your type of  requirement and on DDL changed event try to rebind the Session object with new modified values

Comment: i have 35 items in my collection, all of which i need access to. is there no better approach than using session?

Comment: Going to use a combination of Session and Caching - thanks chaps.